# GEtting the error of no offset line found

Tags: one-simulator

I am running the error of no offset line found. It runs fine if I run the default_settings from the GitHub link but not otherwise.

I tried running it multiple times but as soon as I change anything, it shows me that error. Even if I add something with the first group i.e. Group1, it shows me that error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.